# Checking for Errors Running xcodebuild (Command Line) for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, xcodebuild

I'm currently working on a script to build my iOS projects.

I am able to run the archive command using...

```
xcodebuild -workspace <workspace_name> -scheme <scheme_name> 'archive'
```

But what is the best way to check for errors? If there is a way to do it without parsing the logs, it would be great. However, if parsing the logs is the best way, what's the best string to look for?

I tested for return codes. xcodebuild returns 0 on success, but also when there are build errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using `-project` parameter, you can `build` your project. Goto your `Project.xcodeproj` folder on `terminal`. Then type,

```
xcodebuild -project projectname.xcodeproj
```

Check this [xcodebuild reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) .

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this answers my question. From what I understand, that only builds the specified project.